# how to access phpmyadmin only the port 8080 in apache

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin

I've tried

```
vim /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

but I can not put a VirtualHost here.

I want to change this configuration to list only the port 8080, can anyone help?

thank you

what I want is:

```
www.site.com/phpmyadmin -> failure
www.site.com:8080/phpmyadmin -> OK
```

I want to leave access to port 80 for the rest of the site.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the Listen directive to 8080.

Search the apache configuration for Listen and change it from

```
Listen 80
```

to

```
Listen 8080
```

And restart the server.  Bear in mind, this will be global to the whole apache server though. On centos or redhat, it'll be called "httpd.conf"

Comment: I want to block access to the phpmyadmin port 80 and allow the port 8080.
Where and how to do it?

Comment: But you want to leave access to port 80 for the rest of the site or not?

Comment: I want to leave access to port 80 for the rest of the site

Comment: Do you have root access?  i.e. can you change the main apache config file?

Comment: I have access to the file

Answer (score 0):

Usually the phpmayadmin configuration is included for all the Virtualhosts, that's a package installation behavior, and that's quite bad.

The file `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` is included from the main configuration (sometimes from a file in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf`).

Thoe first thing you could do is remove this *main-all-virtualhosts-inclusion* and only include this file with the `Include` keyword in one Virtualhost.

This allows two things, first you could use a dedicated ServerName for this host. Second you can alter the Port of the Virtualhost (or you can just do one of theses things).
Check [this previous answer about IP/Name Virtualhosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561441/create-an-ip-vhost-in-apache/19565757#19565757), it will help you figure how Virtualhosts works. The Solution for you is to:

- forbid the phpmyadmin configuration inclusion on the main-general-shared configuration level
- Listen on both port 80 and 8080
- Declare two `NameVirtualHost`, one on `*:80` one on `*:8080`
- Use a Virtualhost *:80 for classical application/websites, `ServerName: www.site.com`, ensure phpmyadmin configuration file is not included
- Use a Virtualhost *:8080 including the phpmyadmin configuration, `ServerName: www.site.com`