# Installed Laravel But Phpmyadmin has conflict with Laravel Routes

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

I Have installed Laravel on my Windows. So While accessing http://localhost:8000/phpmyadmin it doesn't seem to be working since it has some kind of conflict with laravel routes.

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

1/1NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why you have wrote phpmyadmin route in your route.php file?

Comment: Sorry didn't get your comment!

Comment: To access phpnyadmin, try localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: can you show line 161 of your routecollection?

Comment: @JilsonThomas without 8000 also not working!

Comment: @ZahanSafallwa

here is the code :

if (count($others) > 0) {
            return $this->getRouteForMethods($request, $others);
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException; // 161
    }

Comment: Can you post your routes here?

Answer (score 1):

javad71

It would appear that your issue is this.  When you run your server for you laravel installation, your system is looking at the /path/to/code/public folder. This folder in the Laravel installation does have an .htaccess file that does some 'magic' for laravel translating the url you visit into the correct route.

Thus, the configuration inside of the phpmyadmin setup is not getting hit when you visit /phpmyadmin from the browser at the root of your laravel project.

A couple suggestions here for this.

1: Change Laravel to not use port 8000 if you can typically run phpmyadmin from that domain.  If you started laravel server by running the artisan command, the port can be changed by running `php artisan serve --port 8888` where 8888 is any other open port.

2: In the PHP My Admin configuration, change the port number it listens on to something else.

-Brian

Comment: phpMyAdmin doesn't specifically listen on a particular port; this is configured in the webserver itself. As a result, there's no phpMyAdmin configuration directive to change the listening port.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch actually it does... see this SO question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601216/how-to-access-phpmyadmin-only-the-port-8080-in-apache

Comment: Okay, then I think we're basically disagreeing about semantics. The configuration file referenced is an Apache configuration file, and Apache is handles incoming HTTP/HTTPS requests. An answer there mentions the path `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` which is an Apache VirtualHost configuration file created by one of the distributions and included automatically as part of the Apache configuration. phpMyAdmin doesn't have a webserver built in, so regardless of which webserver is being used, the listening port is configured in the web server, not phpMyAdmin's `config.inc.php`.

Comment: All I'm saying is that you're quite right that this could be a port conflict, but it's not configured in the phpMyAdmin configuration, and a Windows system isn't going to have an `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` or `/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf`, so the OP must configure the webserver for the listening port.

Answer (score 0):

javed71.

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish but PHPMyadmin is supposed to be installed together with your Apache, PhP and MySQL if you're using XAMPP or WAMP. Visting http://localhost/phpmyadmin and resulting to 404 or PageNotFound error means that there is no running instance of Apache on your machine. However, laravel has a command for running its own service via `php artisan serve`.

If you are trying to just visit `PhPMyAdmin`, make sure you've installed XAMPP, WAMP or any stacked servers. Hope these help.